# Convert from undefined value in json file to string?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file where I have an undefined value of key with a string as shown below:

```
{
                "display_url" : "bit.ly/1Thojq6",
                "indices" : [ 
                    90, 
                    113
                ]
            }
        ],
        "user_mentions" : [],
        "symbols" : [],
        "media" : [ 
            {
                "id" : NumberLong(715690140442734594),
                "id_str" : "715690140442734594",
                "indices" : [ 
                    114, 
                    137
                ],
```

The numbers with the Numberlong do not make it not valid JSON file, So I would like to change it to

```
 {
                "id" : "NumberLong(715690140442734594)",
                "id_str" : "715690140442734594",
                "indices" : [ 
                    114, 
                    137
                ],
```

Comment: Exactly what is `NumberLong` and where does it come from? What library are you using to generate the JSON? Can you provide a [mcve] that shows us what your code roughly looks like.

Comment: It is a given file I am not generating it.

Comment: There are tools trying to "repair" invalid JSON. One of them (no recommendation, but listed, because it can by tested online) is https://github.com/josdejong/jsonrepair

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, then somebody provided you with an invalid JSON file and you need to find a way to make sense of it?

Comment: yes, I did manage to clean it but I need a proper way to convert this to a string.

Comment: If you can be reasonably confident that the string `NumberLong` doesn't appear anywhere else, you could write a regular expression to turn `NumberLong(1)` into `"NumberLong(1)"` if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
json_object["media"][0]["id"] = "NumberLong(715690140442734594)"
a_file = open("your_file.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
a_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have multiple Numbers long in the file not a single entry.